# AVAudioFile in Swift Playground results in "error -54"

Tags: swift, core-audio, swift-playground, avaudiofile

I decided to have a play with AVAudioPlayer in a Swift Playground. The following code works fine in a normal Swift project, but returns the following error when running it in a Playground (in the assistant editor):

> 2015-05-12 00:08:04.374 AVAudioFile[2481:141158] 00:08:04.374 ERROR:     AVAudioFile.mm:266: AVAudioFileImpl: error -54

Here is the code:

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

var audioFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/scooby/Desktop/song.wav")
var error: NSError?
var audioFile = AVAudioFile(forReading: audioFileURL, error: &error)
```

Printing the error out comes with:

> Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=-54 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio error -54.)"
>   UserInfo=0x7fa8c0736f70 {failed
>   call=ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, &_extAudioFile)}

Just can't figure out why its only an error in a Playground. Any ideas at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Xcode 6**

1. Open the Playground *in the Finder* ("Show package contents")
2. Create a "Resources" folder inside
3. Add your file in the folder
4. Quit and relaunch the Playground

To use the file:

```
let audioFileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myFile", withExtension: "wav")
var error: NSError?
let audioFile = AVAudioFile(forReading: audioFileURL, error: &error)
```

**Xcode 7**

No need for a workaround anymore.

Open the Playground's Project Navigator (<kbd>CMD+1</kbd>) then drag & drop your file(s) into the existing "Resources" folder.

To use the file:

```
do {
    if let audioFileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myFile", withExtension: "wav") {
        let audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: audioFileURL)
        // use audioFile here
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Had not realised playgrounds were packages, that now makes sense..and it works too. Many thanks!